# Filter out null in immutable objects list of fields

Tags: kotlin

I have an immutable object:

```
class Foo(
        val name: String,
        val things: List<Thing>
)
```

A third party lib creates the Foo object with some 'null' Thing objects.

I am creating a new object:

```
val foo = thirdPartyGetFoo()
val filteredFoo = Foo(foo.name, foo.things.filterNotNull())
```

That works, however AndroidStudio greys out the filterNotNull function call and presents a warning:

> Useless call on collection type: The inspection reports filter-like
>   calls on already filtered collections.

Is this the right way to filter that list?  Should I ignore the warning or is there a better way?

Comment: `List<Thing>` means you have a list of non-nullable objects, they can't be null by definition, so your filter won't do anything

Comment: Doesn't seem true.  The 3rd party api I am calling is written in Java.  Thinking that 3rd party lib is creating a list that does have nulls in it since optionals are not check in Java.  I have verified that I do indeed have a list with nulls.

Comment: In that case `things` should be declared as `val things: List<Thing?>`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Sucks that I want to protect against null but cannot enforce that if Java creates the object.  Is there a way around that.  Seems like this is going to be a problem with for a long time as I don't think Java libs will go away.

Comment: What 3rd party library is creating the list with nulls, if it is a deserialization library (Gson, Jackson), maybe it has a way to strip the nulls for you, or to use a creator method that does so.

Comment: It could also be the case that `Thing` is an object where all fields could be nullable. In that case null is allowed. So not sure why there is a warning where `filterNotNull()` is shown as useless by the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify what library creates the object with nulls. Some deserialization libraries can use static factory methods which you could configure, and then have the factory method strip the null.  For example, if this were Jackson you would simply:

```
class Foo(val name: String, val things: List<Thing>) {
    companion object {
        @JsonCreator 
        @JvmName("createFromNullable")
        fun create(name: String, things: List<Thing?>) = Foo(name, things.filterNotNull())

        fun create(name: String, things: List<Thing>) = Foo(name, things)
    }
}
```

Then...

```
val goodFoo = jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<Foo>(someJsonWithNulls)
```

Maybe your library has options that are similar?

If not, and you don't have 100 of these things with this problem, I would probably create a temporary class to hold the results and convert that to the final class:

```
open class FooNullable(val name: String, open val things: List<Thing?>) {
    open fun withoutNulls(): Foo = Foo(name, things.filterNotNull())
}

class Foo(name: String, override val things: List<Thing>) : FooNullable(name, things) {
    override fun withoutNulls(): Foo = this
}
```

Then you can deserialize into `FooNullable` and just call `withoutNulls()` to get the other flavor that is clean.  And if you accidentally call it on one without nulls already, it just does nothing.

```
val goodFoo = Foo("", emptyList<Thing>())
val alsoGoodFoo = goodFoo.withoutNulls()        // NOOP does nothing

val badFoo = thirdPartyGetFoo()
val betterFoo = badFoo.withoutNulls()           // clean up the instance

val safeFoo = thirdPartyGetFoo().withoutNulls() // all at once!
```

Not the cleanest, but does work.  The downsides is this second step, although it looks like you were already planning on doing that anyway.  But this model is safer than what you proposed since you KNOW which type of object you have and therefore you continue to be typesafe and have the compiler helping you avoid a mistake.

You don't have to use inheritance as in the above example, I was just trying to unify the API in case there was a reason to have either version in hand and know which is which, and also act upon them in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, and actually I am using GSON.  They do have an instance creator, although doesn't quite work the same as Jacksons @JsonCreator.  I can certainly define a custom deserializer, but that really defeats the purpose of "simple" deserialization being that all I need to do is avoid a list with nulls.

Comment: Well, those are your options, the instance creator, or a 2nd class to keep type safety correct and not end up with a class that contains something dangerous (i.e. nulls within a non nullable item type, would cause random bugs later).

Comment: Yup I get it, just pointing out the shortcoming with Gson as the gason instance creator is not a copy construction like Jackson, it is just a simple way to create an object that doesn't have a default no arg constructor.